# Difference confidence intervals for same data depending on unit?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have a question that comes down to a 100 item sample with a mean of 0.5kg and a variance of 0.056kg. I am trying to calculate the 95% confidence interval. If I do the calculation using grams instead of Kg I get a different answer. I am assuming it's coming down to standard deviation being different as square root of 0.056 is larger while the square root of 56 is small.

Is there a rule or understanding I am missing around converting variance to standard deviation?

Comment: Your variance should not have "kg" as unit. It should be $\text{kg}^2$. And there are $1,000,000 \text{ g}^2$ in $1 \text{kg}^2$, not $1,000$.

Comment: thank you, that explains it as 0.0056 has same standard deviation